# React video tag keeps playing the video in loop. How can i stop it?

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-video

```js
<div style={{ height: "100vh" }} className="clearance">
  <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
    <source
      src={course?.courseAttachments?.attachmentUrl}
      type="video/mp4"
    />
  </video>
</div>
```

I have tried adding different attributes but the video starts again when it finishes running

Answer (score 1):

did you try adding `loop="false"` attribute ?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `src` to this:

```html
src = {course?.courseAttachments?.attachmentUrl} + "&loop=false"
```

Comment: This is not working